# How do I fix - net use "System error 67 has occurred."

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation

[image][image]So I'm in a data warehousing class right now.
We're setting up a VM through VMware workstation using Windows 10 - 32bit. We also had to set up a static IP address for what we're going to be doing. But right now I'm trying to run the code:
C:>net use \*your host name*\C$
For me it would be:
C:>net use \Win10\C$
But every time I run it I get the error that "the network name cannot be found."
I've been working on this all week, tried multiple things, and I just can't get it fixed. Does anyone have any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

The `net use` syntax is incorrect. It should be `net use X: \\<host name>`, where X: is the name you want to give to the remote drive. Assuming `C:` is the root of the remote drive, you will be able to access it via X: now. E.g. `cd X:`

See the full `net use` syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490717(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

The syntax you originally used resembles the one used when you want to access remote drive without mapping (i.e., without `net use`). In such case you can, for example, enter `\\<remote host>\C$` into the explorer window.

Comment: Okay so I ran the syntax that you gave me and now I'm getting "error 85 - local device name is already in use" -- I also shared a screenshot of part of my assignment directions

Comment: Use the command `NET USE X: /DELETE` to remove the drive mapping. Then add it again with `NET USE X: \\WIN10\C$`.

Comment: @hts95 You're trying to map to local C: - you already have it, so it's obviously in use. Map to a new drive, that's not already in use on your local machine - something like Z: or Y: